# asp.net localized resources dll not created in temporary asp.net internet files

Tags: iis-7, localization, 64-bit, application-pool, aspnet-compiler

We are storing our localized resources in a separate assembly from our web application. After using xcopy deployment to our web server, the localized satellite resources.dll files are not being generated (in temporary asp.net files) by the aspnet_compiler.

Occasionally, if we start/stop the app pool, they get created, but there doesn't seem to be any consistency as to when this happens.

Are there any suggestions on where/what to look for to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *in temporary asp.net files*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the the issue was a permissions issue. The location: c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\temporary asp.net files\ didn't have sufficient permisssions. It turns out that the localized files are created based on the person initiating the first request to the application. So, if the account that requested the app didn't have permission to this directory, all files except the localized versions were generated by the asp.net compiler!